# Alert box is not disappearing and app crash

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, flutter-layout, dart-pub

I am trying to go from the 2nd screen to the main screen. The dialog button is doing its job but the **Alert box is not disappearing** and **if again I press the button on the main screen for entering in 2nd screen it shows this error.**

```
Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/second", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.
```

Alert code:

```
onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                //Navigator.pop(context);
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => HomeRoute(),
                    ));
                setState(() {
                  quizBrain.reset();
                  scoreKeeper.clear();
                  trueAns = 0;
                  falseAns = 0;
                });
              },
```

**Main.dart file:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rflutter_alert/rflutter_alert.dart';
import 'Easy.dart';

import 'quiz_brain.dart';
import 'Easy.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    initialRoute: '/',
    routes: {
      '/': (context) => HomeRoute(),
      '/second': (context) => Quizzler(),
      '/third': (context) => Quizzler(),
    },
  ));
}


class HomeRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Geeks for Geeks'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Click Me!'),
                onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');
                },
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Click Me!'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  Quizzler()),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

**Note:**
Second button on main screen don't show the error but alert not disappearing problem remains.

Comment: If you don't use `pop` does route works?

Comment: The same problem occurs which I mention above.

Comment: it's ok if `Alert box is not disappearing` we can handle that later. do you still get route errors after removing `Navigator.of(context).pop();` ?

Comment: yes, getting same error after removing `Navigator.of(context).pop();`

Comment: Can you include your main.dart  including route

Comment: remove route from main and add home on material. while you are declaring `MaterialPageRoute` on push. do you still get the same errors now?

Comment: I add main.dart in my Question you can see now

Comment: in void main now I add `runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomeRoute(),));` and remove the route. App crash problem is solved but Alert still don't disappear.